# Пронумеровать заново елементы коллекции при удалении

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, listbox, observablecollection

Всем привет, имеется `ObservableCollection` следующего содержания:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string desc {get; set;}
}

ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() { id = 1, name = "A", desc = "AAA"},
    new MyClass() { id = 2, name = "B", desc = "BBB"},
    new MyClass() { id = 3, name = "C", desc = "CCC"},
    new MyClass() { id = 4, name = "D", desc = "DDD"},
    new MyClass() { id = 5, name = "E", desc = "EEE"}
};

private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCollection.Add(new MyClass{ id = count + 1, name = Name, desc = Desc});
}
```

Вопрос вот какой: все то, что добавляется в коллекцию, выводится в `ListBox` , id - привязан к `ListBoxItem` и отображается пользователю. Но вот в чем загвоздка, если удалить элемент коллекции, например `3`, то отображается так: `1, 2, 4, 5` и т.д. Можно ли как то при удалении елемента заново пронумеровать их в порядке возрастания. Чтобы отображалось все по порядку: `1, 2, 3, 4` ?

Comment: А зачем вам тут вообще тогда `Id`? Берите индекс, делайте +1 если надо, будет вам отсчитывать тогда 1, 2, 3,4... Ну а если надо вывести лишь нумерование, то это вовсе можно (и нужно) на XAML переложить.

Comment: Можете показать?

Comment: Показать что? Я не знаю, что вы хотите, и для чего вам этот `Id`. Если вам нужен `Id` чтоб потом делать что-то с элементом, например найти (а-ля `var result = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(x=>x is { Id:5 })`), то в таком случае достаточно взять по индексу `var result = MyCollection[4]` (помним, что индекс идет с `0`!). Если вам надо лишь вывести на экран, то привязка будет примерно такой `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"`, но учтите, если много элементов и используется виртуализация, то не гарантируется, что начнет с 0!

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы просто отображать пользователю порядковый номер, а про удалении элемента, чтобы все остальные элементы пронумеровались в порядке возрастания, а номер начинается у меня с 1, поэтому я и добавил сюда ID, он просто служит выводом порядкового номера.

Comment: Еще раз повторю - порядковый номер коллекции - индекс! Не надо изобретать велосипеды, привяжитесь к нему (как - показал выше). Если нужно с 1, то можете использовать конвертор.